# Download the exported file(zip) in C# from api

Tags: java, c#, api

I'm using post and get request from Qualtrics api. They have sample code in java but I have a hard time to convert it into .net environment. The difficulity part is the download exported file(zip file). My question is how to implement the httpClient.execute in C#? I think in java it could hold the object without download into your physical drive and unzip the file.... 
Their sample code in java:

```
HttpGet statusGet = new HttpGet(fileUrl);
statusGet.setHeader("X-API-TOKEN", API_TOKEN);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(statusGet);
   // Extract exported file
    ZipInputStream zs = new ZipInputStream(response.getEntity().getContent());
    ZipEntry entry;
    while ((entry = zs.getNextEntry()) != null)
    {
      FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./" + entry.getName());
      IOUtils.copy(zs, out);
      out.close();
    }
  }
```

Here's mine in c#:

```
using (var clientgetfile = new HttpClient())
{
    clientgetfile.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    clientgetfile.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-API-TOKEN", "mytoken");
    clientgetfile.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/zip"));

    var response =  clientgetfile.GetAsync(fileUrl);
    DownloadFile = response.Result;
    var byteArray = DownloadFile.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
    ....
```